# What authentication to use for .Net application > linux/tikiwiki

Tags: authentication, tiki-wiki

I need some advice on what authentication to use in the following scenario:
I have a .Net winforms application, from within this application a user must be able to click a button, and go to a TikiWiki page on a linux server without having to login again.

The authentication does not have to be user based (for now).
But simply a token that the client session is valid(im guessing here ;))
Can anyone advice on the type of authentication system best to use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do what you need using [Token Access](https://doc.tiki.org/token-access) if you don't need individual user accounts in Tiki, but just controls access to various resources.

If you do need your Windows users to have actual Tiki accounts you could try [LDAP Authentication](https://doc.tiki.org/LDAP-authentication), but i believe there are restrictions on what Tiki supports (i've not ever had to set that up, but i believe others have).

Hope that gets you started?

Comment: Thank you for this info, i am looking into tokens now. The only thing i cannot find is how to generate a new token. I read the docs but it explains to use this url to generate a token: https://yoursite/tiki-ajax_services.php?controller=tracker&action=export_items&trackerId=3&encoding=UTF-8&separator=,&CR=%%%&recordsMax=-1 .

But that makes no sense to me? I think i need another controller and action but i can't find anything in source either. Do you have any idea?
Making a new token each time in the UI does not work for us. We need a dynamic link for external customers.

Comment: Tokens get generated by the https://doc.tiki.org/Share feature links, so try enabling that and you should get a link on each page with the token on it, as far as i can remember (sorry, it's been a while since i tried this).